# Taking the integral image of a Color Distance result (logical error)

Tags: c++, opencv, gpu

I'm debugging a robot's project and have found an error which I'm not quite sure how to fix it theoretically.

I must calculate a color distance map, and following this I must take the integral image of the result and do some calculation with it.

Using the A and B channel from a Lab colorspaced image I obtain the color distance for example color red(pA = 255, pB = 127) using formula sqrt([A-pA]^2+[B-pB]^2)

```
subtract(mA, Scalar(pA), tA);
subtract(mB, Scalar(pB), tB);
tA.convertTo(t32A, CV_32SC1);
tB.convertTo(t32B, CV_32SC1);
pow(t32A, 2.0, powA);
pow(t32B, 2.0, powB);
add(powA, powB, sq);
pow(sq, 0.5, res);
//res.convertTo(result, CV_8UC1);
```

I needed the conversion to CV_32S because of the limitations of CV_8U handling values above 255.

Now I must feed the result in to the integral image, this expects only an image of CV_8UC1.

The problem I'm facing, is that the aforementioned color distance function might produce pixels with values above 255.

For example:
distance between (0,0) to red (255,127)

sqrt( (0-255)^2 + (0-127)^2) = 285

Or between (0,255) to red (255,127)

sqrt( (0-255)^2 + (255-127)^2) = 285

Does anybody have any suggestions how I can feed the result in to the integral image, without any loss of information.

Thank you

Comment: I think you would like to rectify errors in your example.

Comment: What's wrong with the example, I've rewritten, perhaps it makes more sense now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using sqrt(2) as a normalization factor ?

Comment: I don't understand your solution... Can you elaborate? Thanks in advance

Comment: The maximum value which you could get out of such comparison is sqrt(255^2 + 255^2). To bring it within a range of 0 to 255 you can divide it with sqrt(2). Hence if you divide any such value with sqrt(2) it is guranteed that the result will fall between 0 to 255.

Comment: Okidoki, seems simple enough.